# how to change authority of mint account?

Tags: anchor, spl-token, spl-token-program

i'm trying to change the authority of token mint to a pda so only the program can mint

```
 pub fn into_set_authority_context(&self) -> CpiContext<'_, '_, '_, 'info, SetAuthority<'info>> {
        let cpi_accounts = SetAuthority {
            account_or_mint: self.token_mint.to_account_info().clone(),
            current_authority: self.current_owner.to_account_info().clone(),
        };
        CpiContext::new(self.token_program.to_account_info().clone(), cpi_accounts)
    }
```

```
anchor_spl::token::set_authority(
        ctx.accounts.into_set_authority_context(),
        AuthorityType::AccountOwner,
        Some(authority),
    ).expect("set_authority failed");
```

But I get an error:

```
     Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xf
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert 0xF to decimal (15),  then visiting https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/error.rs

You'll find at the #15th position the error is:   #[error("Account does not support specified authority type")]